# Search Ldap tool to validate username/password by an API

Tags: json, active-directory, ldap

I'm looking for a tool that I can host (preferably a docker) that connects to an Active Directory and responds via API.

I just want to validate the usernames/passwords entered by users with a simple return. At best recover user groups from the AD account. With at least one authentication token this is the minimum.

I found the solution

https://connect2id.com/products/ldapauth

But it pays off ...

I didn't manage to get my hands on an equivalent product, anyone with a proposal?

lemonldap for use her API but I can't connect to active directory Server ...